# How to make my Discord.js bot say something when joning a Discord guild?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make my bot send a welcome message when he joins a Guild, but i don't know how, tried to do something but it didn't worked. How can I do that?

Code that not worked:

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    message.channel.send('¡Hola! Soy el bot de Pepelui85, mi prefix aquí es "*" y mis comandos son: *pc y *llora.');
    message.channel.send('¿Encontraste algun bug? Reportalo en el canal desarrollo de mi servidor de Discord.');
    message.channel.send('https://discord.gg/3taae9');
});
```

Comment: Where exactly do you see `message` being defined? Guilds can have multiple channels, where did you expect the bot to send those messages?

Comment: Also it's best to explain what "didn't work" -> Did you receive errors? Did you get a result that you didn't expect? Please look at what @Wright said AND describe what went wrong / what "didn't work"

Answer (score 0):

try do

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {

let SendChannel = guild.channels.get("general") || guild.channels.get("chat");

SendChannel.send('¡Hola! Soy el bot de Pepelui85, mi prefix aquí es "*" y mis comandos son: *pc y *llora.');

Sendchannel.send('¿Encontraste algun bug? Reportalo en el canal desarrollo de mi servidor de Discord.');

SendChannel.send('https://discord.gg/3taae9');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

or just do this!

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {

let SendChannel = guild.channels.find("name", "general") || guild.channels.find("name", "chat");

if(SendChannel) SendChannel.send('¡Hola! Soy el bot de Pepelui85, mi prefix aquí es "*" y mis comandos son: *pc y *llora. \n¿Encontraste algun bug? Reportalo en el canal desarrollo de mi servidor de Discord. \nhttps://discord.gg/3taae9');

});
```